# Swift: How to resolve subscript ambiguity. Named subscripts?

Tags: swift, named-parameters

I've implemented an ordered dictionary, which has two subscripts. The first is for the index (always of type `Int`) and the second is for the key of variing type `keyType`.

This all works fine until `keyType` is `Int`, because now the subscripts are obviously ambiguous.

> Ambiguous use of 'subscript'

So to resolve to ambiguity, I tried to simply add a name tag `key:` for the value, just like normal function parameters have them, but this resulted in `key: keyType` being seen as my parameter type, which resulted in this error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'OrderedDictionary' with an index of type '(key: Int)'

The error messages are very clear to me, yet I don't know how to resolve the ambiuity. For now I am using a function `insert(for:value:)`.

Here is the OrderedDictionary class:

```
import Foundation

struct OrderedDictionary<keyType: Hashable, valueType>: Sequence {
    typealias Element = (keyType, valueType)

    let comparator: ((Element, Element) -> (Bool))?
    var keys = [keyType]()
    var values = [keyType:valueType]()
    var count: Int {
        get {
            return keys.count
        }
    }

    public struct Iterator: IteratorProtocol {
        let parent: OrderedDictionary
        var position: Int = 0

        init(parent: OrderedDictionary) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        mutating func next() -> (keyType, valueType)? {
            if position == parent.keys.count {
                return nil
            }
            let entry = parent.getEntry(at: position)
            position += 1
            return entry
        }
    }

    init() {
        comparator = nil
    }

    init(comparator:  ((Element, Element) -> (Bool))?) {
        self.comparator = comparator
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> valueType? {
        get {
            return self.values[self.keys[index]]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            let key = self.keys[index]
            if newValue == nil {
                self.keys.remove(at: index)
                self.values.removeValue(forKey: key)
            } else {
                self.values[key] = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    subscript(key: keyType) -> valueType? {
        get {
            return self.values[key]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            if newValue == nil {
                for i in (0..<self.keys.count) {
                    if self.keys[i] == key {
                        self.keys.remove(at: i)
                        break
                    }
                }
                self.values.removeValue(forKey: key)
            } else {
                insert(for: key, value: newValue!)
            }
        }
    }

    mutating func insert(for key: keyType, value: valueType) {
        let oldValue = self.values.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
        if oldValue == nil {
            if comparator != nil {
                for i in (0..<self.keys.count) {
                    if comparator!((key, value), getEntry(at: i)) {
                        self.keys.insert(key, at: i)
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
            //First key, largest key or insertion order
            self.keys.append(key)
        }
    }

    func getEntry(at index: Int) -> Element {
        let key = self.keys[index]
        return (key, self.values[key]!)
    }

    func makeIterator() -> OrderedDictionary<keyType, valueType>.Iterator {
        return Iterator(parent: self)
    }

    mutating func removeAll() {
        self.keys.removeAll()
        self.values.removeAll()
    }
}
```

And here the some examples in Swift:

```
//Note: Index type 'Int' same as key type 'Int'
var dict = OrderedDictionary<Int, String>()

// Ambiguous
dict[0] = "Hello"

// Named (not valid)
dict[key: 10] = "World"

// Workaround
dict.insert(for: 20, value: "!")
```

How do I resolve this ambiguity? Is this even possible in Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift subscript with argument label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57992996/swift-subscript-with-argument-label)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike all other functions in Swift, subscript parameter names are not externalized by default. (I regard this inconsistency as a bug in the language.)

So, where you have

```
subscript(key:
```

...you need to say

```
subscript(key key:
```

...in order to expose the `key` label to the caller.

---

Actually, it sounds to me like what you want is three subscripts:

```
subscript(index: Int)
subscript(key: keyType)
subscript(key key: keyType)
```

That way you can say `key` in the call only just in case ambiguity would result if you didn't.

Comment: Actually, since you will probably access by key more than by index, you might want `index` to be exposed label. Or you could expose both.

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice to have optional labels (just in case of an ambiguity), but this works.

Comment: Well, I don't think your other solution (a method instead of a subscript) is all that bad. Subscripts are nice but they are just a convenience. Swift Dictionary subscripts do not allow you to do anything you couldn't do by calling methods, for example. We are so accustomed to using the subscripts that we forget the methods even exist.

Comment: Oh, by the way, sure, you could have optional labels, just add yet another subscript. I'll add that to my answer.