# Swift subscript with argument label

Tags: swift, label, subscript

Is it possible to create a subscript that can be invoked with explicit argument labels?

```
struct MyType {
    subscript (label: Bool) -> String? {
        return nil
    }
}

let test = MyType()
let value1 = test[true] // ok
let value2 = test[label: true] // Extraneous argument label 'label:' in subscript
```

Attempting to use the label results in the error:

> Extraneous argument label 'label:' in subscript

The new key path feature looks like it uses subscripts with argument labels, but that may be compiler magic that isn't available to the public:

```
let value = someThing[keyPath: \.property]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

External argument labels in `subscript` aren't used by default, so unlike for normal functions, if you want to have external argument labels, you need to specify that explicitly.

```
struct MyType {
    subscript(label label: Bool) -> String? {
        return nil
    }
}

let test = MyType()
let value = test[label: true]
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I saw this statement written in Ray Wenderlich's [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9088-custom-subscripts-in-swift) but for some reason it didn't click that it meant writing it twice. I was like "but `subscript (label: Bool) -> String?` _is_ explicit!"

Comment: @jeremyabannister glad I could help :) Yeah, this is quite a confusing implementation detail, especially because it is opposite to what normal functions do.